# password alphanumeric php without use regex

Tags: php, passwords, alphanumeric

i just try like this.

```
for($i=0;$i<$length;i++)
{
    if(!ctype_alpha($password[$i])
    {
        header("location:regist.php?err=Password not contain letter");

    }
    else if(!is_numeric($password[$i]))
    {
        header("location:regist.php?err=Password not contain  numbers");
    }
    else
    {
        //??
    }
}
```

how to validate password if the password must alphanumeric without using regular expression ?

Comment: You should not force your users to make their passwords less complicated.

Comment: this is for school task

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `ctype_alnum`
Check- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php

UPDATE-

You can check for special characters in your string by something like-

```
<?php
$test = "password123";

$special_char = "#$%^&*()+=-[]';,./{}|:<>?~";

if (false === strpbrk($test, $special_char))
{

    echo "Good Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: There is a huge difference between a white-list and a black-list. There is no way you can reliably get all non-alphanumeric characters in your black-list. Your original answer was a lot better :-)

Comment: i have use ctype_alnum but when the pass is 'test' only string, the pass is true. is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

( may be this is ugly coding) but this is what you need

```
$str="123adsd##$";

$error ='string should be alphanumeric';

$str1 = str_replace(range(0,9), '', $str);

$alph = array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z'));

if(strlen($str1)>strlen($str) || strlen($str1)<strlen($str))
{
    $str2 = str_replace($alph, '', $str1);

if(strlen($str2)>strlen($str1) || strlen($str2)<strlen($str1))
{
  if(strlen($str2) >0)
  {
    echo $error;
  }
}
else{
    echo $error;
}
}
else{
    echo $error;
}
```

***output***

```
string should be alphanumeric
```